# do we still need to detect neon support at runtime with the new abi arm64-v8a?

Tags: android, android-ndk, neon

I know that we had to check for neon availability with the previous arm-v7a abi, I'd like to know if it is still the case or we can compile only one executable with neon instructions (which I prefer of course).

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

NEON is mandatory for the license on ARMv8 and on.

There is no need to check its availability therefore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that NEON is mandatory on ARMv8-A, on ARMv8-R only Thumb-2 is mandatory.